# Snapkit - is there a difference between right.width.center and right, width, center?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, snapkit

`make.right.width.center equalTo(superview).offset(-20)`

vs

```
make.right.equalTo(superview).offset(-20)
make.width.equalTo(superview).offset(-20)
make.center.equalTo(superview).offset(-20)
```

- is there a different when positioning any object (label, image, etc). I was reviewing another dev's code & thought one of two things: 1. This is grouped positioning, really efficient. Then, I thought man, could this be the right side's width and center anchors?.. Bit confused lol. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes , same effect

```
 greenView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.right.width.centerX.centerY.equalTo(view).offset(-20)
            make.height.equalTo(130)
        }
```

is equal to

```
   greenView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.right.equalTo(view).offset(-20)
            make.width.equalTo(view).offset(-20)
            make.center.equalTo(view).offset(-20)
            make.height.equalTo(130)
        }
```

---

**You can read from the source code**

The process is of 2 parts ,

**set data , then active the layout constraints**

---

- The set data part of the  `make.right.width.centerX.centerY.equalTo(view).offset(-20)`

`make.right` creates a `ConstraintMakerExtendable`

```
public var right: ConstraintMakerExtendable {
        return self.makeExtendableWithAttributes(.right)
    }
```

calls

```
internal func makeExtendableWithAttributes(_ attributes: ConstraintAttributes) -> ConstraintMakerExtendable {
        let description = ConstraintDescription(item: self.item, attributes: attributes)
        self.descriptions.append(description)
        return ConstraintMakerExtendable(description)
    }
```

`make.right.width` , means the `ConstraintMakerExtendable`'s `description.attributes` add  a width `ConstraintAttributes`

```
public var width: ConstraintMakerExtendable {
        self.description.attributes += .width
        return self
    }
```

The final `.offset(-20)`, means the `ConstraintMakerExtendable`'s offset is set

```
@discardableResult
    public func offset(_ amount: ConstraintOffsetTarget) -> ConstraintMakerEditable {
        self.description.constant = amount.constraintOffsetTargetValue
        return self
    }
```

---

- The the active the layout constraints part of the  `make.right.width.centerX.centerY.equalTo(view).offset(-20)`

The implementation of `makeConstraints{ make in }`

```
internal static func makeConstraints(item: LayoutConstraintItem, closure: (_ make: ConstraintMaker) -> Void) {
        // prepare  the layout constraints 
        let constraints = prepareConstraints(item: item, closure: closure)
        //  active the layout constraints
        for constraint in constraints {
            constraint.activateIfNeeded(updatingExisting: false)
        }
    }
```

prepare  the layout constraints

the key point is `description.constraint`

```
 internal static func prepareConstraints(item: LayoutConstraintItem, closure: (_ make: ConstraintMaker) -> Void) -> [Constraint] {
        let maker = ConstraintMaker(item: item)
        closure(maker)
        var constraints: [Constraint] = []
        for description in maker.descriptions {
             // the key point
            guard let constraint = description.constraint else {
                continue
            }
            constraints.append(constraint)
        }
        return constraints
    }
```

`description.constraint` inits the layout constraint

`class Constraint`  has an attribute `layoutConstraints`, which is of  `[LayoutConstraint]`.

`LayoutConstraint` inherits from `NSLayoutConstraint`

**here the offset of description works**

```
internal lazy var constraint: Constraint? = {
        guard let relation = self.relation,
              let related = self.related,
              let sourceLocation = self.sourceLocation else {
            return nil
        }
        let from = ConstraintItem(target: self.item, attributes: self.attributes)
        
        return Constraint(
            from: from,
            to: related,
            relation: relation,
            sourceLocation: sourceLocation,
            label: self.label,
            multiplier: self.multiplier,
            constant: self.constant,      // here  it is
            priority: self.priority
        )
    }()
```

---

- So that case is easy,

  ```
  make.right.equalTo(superview).offset(-20)
  make.width.equalTo(superview).offset(-20)
  make.center.equalTo(superview).offset(-20)
  ```

three `ConstraintMakerExtendable` with the same offset description